# In flash as3 webcam recorder how to reconnect or republish after connection loss

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, webcam, video-capture, flash-media-server

I have a flash as3 based webcam video recorder that **publishes** the webcam video stream of a user to a Flash Media Server (FMS). The trouble I have is that when the connection of the user drops due to erratic internet connection, the recording stops abruptly in between and the video file is more often than not, corrupted. I can use the `NetConnection.Connect.Closed` and `NetConnection.Connect.NetworkChange` events of the `NetConnection` class to detect a connection drop and reconnect to the server without any problems. But on attaching the newly reconnected `NetConnection` object to the `NetStream` object, the recording is reset and starts all over.

In the case of **playback** using an FMS, the re-attaching of a new `NetConnection` to the `NetStream`, there are ways to resume the playback from the last position as shown in the documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WSae44d1d92c7021ff-1f5381712889cd7b56-8000.html. But while **publishing / recording**, I can't resume the recording once i have re-connected. Is there a way to work around this? Ping me in the comments if the question is not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, I've never done this, so I don't know how it would work w/files that are corrupted, but there is an option to append to an existing stream (or append with a gap), when publishing a `NetStream`. The second parameter of the [publish()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#publish%28%29) method specifies how to publish the stream:

```
ns.publish('myStreamName', 'append');
```

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction. I had come across this earlier but didn't spend too much time on it. Will give it a go again and accept the answer if i can get it right...